# Which values can be reached by period doubling bifurcation of the logistic Map?

Tags: chaos-theory

We know, that the first period doubling bifurcation oscilates between $\frac{1}{2r}(r+1 \pm \sqrt{(r-3)(r+1)}$. We speak of the logistic map.

We see, that there is a quadratic term. Does that mean, that by changing r with infinite precision, there will be some values that the oscillation will not reach, no matter which r you chose?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but for $r \ge 3$, $\frac{1}{2r}\left(r+1+\sqrt{(r-3)(r+1)}\right)$ takes on all real values in $[2/3, 1)$ and $\frac{1}{2r}\left(r+1+\sqrt{(r-3)(r+1)}\right)$ takes on all real values in $(0,2/3]$.

Comment: Say I want to reach $n$. Now, set $\frac{1}{2r} (r+1+\sqrt{(r+1)(r-3)}=n$. Algebra says : $(r+1)(r-3) = (2nr-r-1)^2$. This is a quadratic equation. There can be values of $n$ where $r$ will have no real solution. Or am I seeing it wrong? Thank you

Comment: @Robert, I think you've missed out the minus in $\pm$.

Comment: Robert's comment tells you, Sean, that that quantity only evaluates to numbers strictly between zero and one, so those are the values of $n$ you can "reach".  By the way, "whoch"? "peropd"?

Comment: Sorry, that last $\frac{1}{2r} \left(r+1+\sqrt{(r-3)(r+1)}\right)$ should have been $\frac{1}{2r} \left(r+1-\sqrt{(r-3)(r+1)}\right)$

Comment: Sorry was typing from a phone, and I have installed English auto correct just now

Comment: What system is this about? The logistic map? Please [edit] your question to clarify.